# how to use truncate in CTE

Tags: sql, oracle

```
With TruncateCTE(Empid,Name)
as
(
select *
from truncatetest
where Empid=10
)
truncate table TruncateCTE
```

But it is showing an error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'truncate'.
Please help me to solve this...

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Your  question makes no sense whatsoever. What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `TRUNCATE` is a DDL operation, which means remove **ALL** of the rows. You cannot remove **SOME** rows and leave other rows in the table.

And, the `WITH` clause may be processed as an inline view or resolved as a temporary table. So, there is no point in truncating it.

So, your query makes no sense at all.

If you are looking to remove some rows from a table, then `DELETE` is what is meant for it. But, since you have mixed subquery factory and truncate, the entire question is invalid.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are not using a DDL inside a CTE, you are using the (result of) a CTE inside a DDL - that _is_ something different.

Comment: That's what I said, Oracle does allow DDLs like CREATE ***using the resultset returned by the subquery(CTE)***. If that has created a confusion, I would remove the test case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `delete`:

```
delete from truncatetest
    where Empid = 10;
```

In most databases, CTEs are simply subqueries, and you cannot use a subquery with `truncate`.  Stick with the good old-fashioned `delete` statement.

Note that Postgres does allow some DDL statements in CTEs (although not Oracle as far as I know), but I still don't think it allows `truncate`.